# Linear model or component analysis on timecourse data

Tags: time-series, pca, lme4-nlme

I have some timecourse data which plotted looks like the figure below.
I want to better describe the difference between the two conditions.

My adviser advised :D me to use a linear model and observe a time effect (interesting!) a main condition effect (probably none) and a condition*time effect (most interesting).

Now, I am wondering what this information would look like - the time course isn't gradual, and I have run similar tests with R's `lme4::lmer` and `nlme:lme` and for continuous variables (in my case time) they just output one value as if the progression is linear. Obviously in my case it is not :-/

[image]

I have previously worked with such data and used PCA (which indeed, does not give me just-linear progressions) - would it be a good substitute for a linear model in my case? Also, the problem with PCA is that I have no idea how to reap the added information one would get from single participants (with mixed models, I can just add the participant IDs as random variables and feed it the raw data) - is there any way to pass the entire (un-meaned) per-participant data to, say Python's `mdp.pca()` and get something reasonable out of that?

Comment: For PCA you would do exactly the same thing for the mixed model. You would just treat each project as having a `Participant` effect. Something like: `lmer(PC1_scores ~ Var1 + Var2 + (1|Participant)`. (If I understand what you mean by your PCA problem.)

Comment: I was thinkinf of using the PCA *instead* of the mixed model. What you just said runs the mixed model on the PCA results.

Comment: I thought that was what you asked for because you said : *"with PCA is that I have no idea how to reap the added information one would get from single participants"*. I must have misunderstood what you meant; my bad. On second thought then: Why confine yourself with one or the other? Check *Multilevel functional principal component analysis* by Di et al. (2009); I believe they do what you are asking for.