# Mixed model fitted on time course data

Tags: r, time-series, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have some time course data which plotted looks like this:

[image]

I have fitted a mixed model to my raw datapoints with R's `lme4::lmer`, as seen in [this code](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.github.com/TheChymera/7669971/raw/e35bc10d5b6443d28eca44bce8cf17eaa7bf1a8a/TC_lme4).

In essence I get the following output for my model:

measurement~condition*time:

```
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID       (Intercept) 1118082  1057.4  
 Residual               58680   242.2  
Number of obs: 5784, groups: ID, 12

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  2480.379    305.375   8.122
CoIhard       -90.294     12.659  -7.133
Time          -17.326      3.884  -4.461
CoIhard:Time   62.931      5.492  11.458

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) CoIhrd Time  
CoIhard     -0.021              
Time        -0.025  0.611       
CoIhard:Tim  0.018 -0.864 -0.707
```

Now, what am I to make of these results? As I predicted in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77486/linear-model-or-component-analysis-on-timecourse-data) the factors only get one intercept value each, as if they would follow a steady linear increase/decrease. Obviously my time course does not.

What added information pertaining to the description of the difference between my conditions does fitting this model give me?

Cheers,

Comment: If you are dealing with time series, you should should test/model autocorrelation of residuals. This is currently not implemented in `lme4::lmer`, which is one of the main reasons why I still often use `nlme:lme`. I recommend reading "Mixed Effects Models and Extensions in Ecology with R" by Zuur et al., which is a nice introduction for beginners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) your constant = 2480! Where does that fit on the graph?
(2) Graph doesn't have axis labels /legend. Looks like fitted data.
(3) is time a linear term in this model? why?  Have you tried fitting quadratic terms, cubic terms, quartic terms...
- unless the change in scale is distorting the graph, the time trend is clearly non-linear and using a simple linear term lacks face validity. I'd build a main effects model first (time time2, time time2 time3 etc. where time2=time^2 and time3=time^3), find which one fitted best and then consider adding interaction terms. Your categorical would need to interact with each time term if you wanted to add an interaction. I would also test to see if you need the interactions
- how you represent that in R is not clear to me (I usually use Stata)
- There are other ways of handling non-linearity from piecewise models, to I think there is a mixed-effects GAM package. But this is a solid and traditional approach.
(4) have you considered time as a random slope?
(5) have you done residual diagnostics?
- simplest would be to generate histograms of your level-1 and level-2 standardized residuals. but I think the linear time assumption is the key.
(6) have you plotted predicted vs. actual?
- from the model you should be able to predict a mean/model averaged trajectory over time. If you do this with the above model it should be clear that it doesn't fit the data at all. Or show that it sort of does fit the data.

I don't think you're at the "what does this model tell me" stage yet. It's always hard to tell from just a snapshot like this, sorry if I'm way off base and wasting your time, but does seem like you still have a lot of model refinement to do.

Comment: 1,2 - the graphic shown is normed. (the y axis represents value / mean of values); 3 - I was unaware one could do that does that work via this formula measurement~condition*time**2+(1|ID)?; 4 - I do that by setting measurement~condition+(1|time*ID) ?; 5 - no, I was unaware such a thing existed; 6 - what do you mean by that?

Comment: @TheChymera (1) I've added some text (2) I'm assuming a "growth curve" paradigm, you could also approach is as "longitudinal" or as someone mentions above as "time series". They can be different. The terms might help with google searching. (3) mixed models are just regular models with some added complexity to adjust SE for clustering - I'd consider applying linear regression (+/-robust SE) to the data with a few models until you have some idea of the forms of the linear predictors that might fit the data and then move on the the mixed effects world.

Comment: @TheChymera thought you might find this interesting. new approach for me but seems like it might capture what you're looking for (?) and it is codes in R which might be useful: http://www.danmirman.org/gca

Comment: How could I try to re-construct my time course from the above mentioned factors? is it as simple as $easy(x) = -17x + 2480$ and $hard(x) = (62-17)x + 2480 - 90$

Comment: Yes. Sorry. I think this was your original question and I went in a different direction. Easy starts at a higher baseline and declines over time, hard starts at a lower baseline and increases over time. You can overlay these two straight lines over your data (easy=green and hard=purple). The fit captures the key idea that the one series decreases over time and the second decreases. It isn't a bad fit if you ignore time 0 to 0.5 on the graph. If this time period is important a straight line won't really capture data.

Comment: yes, it is that simple